# Union on muliple tables in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am using C# and trying to do union on multiple datatables in the code.

```
Table 1

ID | Value | Value2
-----------------
1  | Tom   | Null
-----------------
2  | John  | Null
-----------------    
...

Table 2

ID | Value | Value2
-----------------
1  | Null  | Susie
-----------------
2  | Null  | Kim
-----------------    
...
```

And, I want the result table would be something like

```
TableResult

ID | Value | Value2
-----------------
1  | Tom   | Susie
-----------------
2  | John  | Kim
-----------------    
...
```

Is there a way I could this?

Comment: Is this in a SQL database? Are you using LINQ-2-SQL or do you need to know how to do this in regular SQL? BTW: What you're describing is called a LEFT JOIN, not a union.

Comment: What data structure do you have this data in right now? A collection? Typically that would be done at the database layer, not the C# layer; if you're using LINQ thats a different story though, as its done in the C# layer which then tells the database layer to do the union.

Comment: The way I'm reading this, it sounds like you want to merge the two tables. If so, what happens in case of conflict (e.g. if Table 1, Value2 was not null)?

Comment: I am trying to do this in C# code, but I guess I can dump the data into the database and do the join. I was trying to see if I can just do this without the actual database. Thanks everyone.

Comment: What data structure is your data in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what datastructure you are using in C#, but you can do this right in your database:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Table1.ID, Table2.ID) AS ID
    ,COALESCE(Table1.Value, Table2.Value) AS Value
    ,COALESCE(Table1.Value2, Table2.Value2) AS Value2
FROM Table1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2
   ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

I chose a FULL OUTER JOIN here so that items could be missing on EITHER side (I generally expect most people will use a FULL OUTER JOIN about once a year in their careers), as well as an arbitrary choice to always pick the value in Table1 if it existed first, so Table2 would not overwrite something in Table1.

So as an example of how the FOJ works:

```
Table 1
1,A,NULL
2,B,X
3,NULL,Y
4,D,Z

Table 2
1,NULL,P
2,NULL,Q
3,C,NULL
5,E,W

Output:
1,A,P
2,B,X
3,C,Y
4,D,Z
5,E,W
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give you Tom | Susie, Tom | Kim, John | Susie, John | Kim? From the example I think you want to do an inner join, not an outer.

Comment: @Joel C, I chose a full outer join because the problem seemed underspecified.  I'll post more in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If they're already in DataTables, you could load them into another table:

```
DataTable unionTable = new DataTable();
unionTable.Load(table1.CreateDataReader());
unionTable.Load(table2.CreateDataReader());
```

I think the notion of doing it server side as previously mentioned is a lot better approach though...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this in Linq

//Lets say you have two tables (fill the variables from dababase)
IQueryable tab1 = new List().AsQueryable();
IQueryable tab2 = new List().AsQueryable();

//You can create Result table this way
 var resultTable = tab1.Select(t1 => new Table1 { t1.ID, t1.Value, tab2.Any(t2 => t2.ID == t1.ID) ? tab2.First(t2 => t2.ID == t1.ID).Value : null });